# Need Help in Android Studio layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I was putting in an email text in my design window and now, it looks like this
[The design layout is in landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkyOq.png)  how to change it back to normal mode?

Answer (score 0):

Change the orientation of the screen from side menu as shown in image[image]